# Knockout binding to change element sizes for bootstrap. RFC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a request for comment to see if I'm way off base with how I use Bootstrap (with the help of KO).

I'm somewhat new to Knockout (but loving it), and VERY new to BootStrap (using v3).  I find now that I've been working with BootStrap 3 for a week or so, I've got a decent understanding of it.  I quite like how you can put multiple classes for col widths (at different screen sizes) and the media queries will take care of it.  Unfortunately, I believe I need the same sort of thing for button / input sizes.

I'm trying to keep BootStrap as vanilla as possible (without many css overrides/changes) so that the same techniques will be applicable across all of my future projects.

As part of that, I have run into issues where I need to resize my buttons based on the screen widths.  The best method I could come up with, is a knockout binding that looks at the screen size and adjusts the CSS class.

I'm looking for comments or alternatives.  I know about the visible-* and hidden-* but feel that'll bloat my markup quite a bit (RFC?).

I have a sample of what I'm talking about, the code is quick and crude just to demonstrate my point.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/bp4twzfb

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use any javascript for modifying css for something like screen widths. You can just use @media rules, which is what bootstrap itself uses.

Here's a simple example of what you could do:

```
@media(max-width:990px){
  .btn{
    padding: 0 5px;  
  }
}
```

That'll make all buttons shrink down (due to less padding) when the screen is equal to or narrower than 990px.

Same principle to make them really big (more padding and larger font-size) on widescreen (1200px+)

```
@media(min-width:1200px){
  .btn{
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 20px 30px;  
  }
}
```

Just make whatever changes you want at the necessary widths and it should work.

Since you're using vanilla bootstrap, these are the breakpoints you'll want to use

```
@media(min-width:768px) /* for small screens like tablets */

@media(min-width:992px) /* for large screens like laptops and large tablets */

@media(min-width:1200px) /* for extra large screens like desktop monitors */
```

If you want to make any changes for mobile, just write your css outside and before those @media blocks. Bootstrap works in mobile-first, which means that it starts out with the mobile styling, then builds up layer by layer with modifications for each larger screen size.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doug thanks.  Maybe it's just that I'm not the strongest CSS guy, but to me it seems more tricky when I want to make certain buttons smaller, and leave others as-is.  I think I'm better with code than I am with CSS.

In thinking about it, I could probably make a btn-xs-xs, btn-sm-xs, btn-md-xs, etc.,  wrap media queries around the btn-xs-* and have them respond to the screen size.  

So I could have a <button class="btn btn-xs-sm btn-lg-lg"/> so that when the screen size is extra small, the button will be small, when the screen size is large (1200 +), the button will be large.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doug, after trying some things out with a colleague, I think that you're right.  I've made some CSS that needs some serious optimization, but I think does the trick for me.  For me, it gives me ultimate flexibility.  I've worked out a sample that uses pure CSS, and it's MUCH quicker.  I think it's something I can live with.  Do it once, put it in another file, and use it when I use bootstrap.  http://cssdeck.com/labs/cazmh7ta